# List View with Custom Section Header

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, header

I'm working on implementing a screen in my android app. I need to implement a **custom** **layout**

I am thinking of implementing this layout using a List View with Section Header. I am following this tutorial https://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android for the implementation.

I want a custom section header like mine. I'm not knowing where I should make changes in the above tutorials **CustomAdapter** class.
Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this custom section header and if possible could you share any references?

Answer (score 0):

First You have to make changes in snippet_item1.xml file as your own design and according to that need to change custom adapter file

Comment: Hey I need to make changes in snippet_item1.xml or snippet_item2.xml? I have added my image View and textview in snippet_itme2.xml. My doubt is what changes I should make in CustomAdapter file?

Comment: make changes in snippet_item1.xml, as 2 is never used in any java file

Answer (score 0):

You need to do necessary changes in both layout files as `snippet_item1.xml` and `snippet_item2.xml`. Later on you need to create two custom `ViewHolder` class for your basic requirement as your views are different then example. Inside `getView()` you need to modify code and assign values for them.

Refer below link for solving your issue:
https://inducesmile.com/android/add-header-to-android-recyclerview/

Anything else required then I will help you via comment section.

Comment: Thanks Sahil. My issue is resolved already. I have created two Model classes separately and also made respective changes in snippet layouts and CustomAdapter.

Comment: @KunduriRaj Great! Update your question if possible and set there it is resolved, so no one else give there output related to this question. Thanks!

Comment: A small doubt. If you see in my image there is a imageView, textViews and buttons.In my Model class I am able to define/declare my imageView as Integer data type and textView as String data type. How can I handle the buttons in Model Class like which data type I should assign? Is this possible or not?

Comment: @KunduriRaj You need to prepare listener for getting click event to your activity or fragment. You can refer that from this link: https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9 or you can find other ways anywhere online